# Run exe file once to generate 5 random numbers 0-9 in assembly

Tags: assembly, random, numbers, masm32

I want to generate 5 random numbers ranging from 0-9 by running the exe once. For example, I run random.exe once and I could get 7,1,3,9,2.
I've used the code below before but it randomizes only once when you run the exe.

```
mov ah, 00h   ; get current time        
int 1ah       ; cx:dx ---> clock count  

mov  ax, dx   ; move low-order part of clock count to ax
xor  dx, dx
mov  cx, 10
div  cx       ; remainder goes to dx (ranges from 0-9)
              ; dx contains the randomized number
mov ax, dx
call printNum   ; prints the contents of ax
```

I tried putting this in a loop but the random number(dx) doesn't change.

Comment: Your code is running too fast, the clock doesn't increment during that time. Even if it did, it wouldn't be much of a random number that way.

Answer (score 0):

result of `int 1ah` with ah(00) indicates the tick count, or clocks, instead of CPU cycles, thus, it is increased each some time (e.g., some micro seconds). That's why even you repeat the code, it is still too fast comparing to the increment interval.
The instruction `rdtsc` may be one solution for your purpose, it offers you the CPU cycles.

For information of `rdtsc`, you may check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any timed counters for random number generation, regardless of which counter you will use. The only way to make such trick is to introduce human dependable pause between number generation. In fact, the first generated number will be more or less random.

So, the only approach if you need five numbers is to use some pseudo-random algorithm and to use `rdtsc` as a random seed value for it.

Something like this:

```
include "%lib%/freshlib.inc"
@BinaryType console
include "%lib%/freshlib.asm"

start:
        InitializeAll

; get the seed:
        rdtsc
        xor     eax, edx
        mov     ebx, eax        ; the seed is in ebx
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     ecx, 50

; generate the numbers
.loop:
        add     ebx, $811C9DC5  ; prime 1
        imul    ebx, $01000193  ; prime 2

        mov     eax, ebx
        xor     edx, edx
        div     esi         ; make it from 0 to 9

        stdcall NumToStr, edx, ntsDec or ntsUnsigned
        stdcall StrCharCat, eax, $0a0d
        push    eax
        stdcall FileWriteString, [STDOUT], eax
        stdcall StrDel ; from the stack

        loop    .loop

        FinalizeAll
        stdcall TerminateAll, 0
```

In order to compile this source, you will need [Fresh IDE](http://fresh.flatassembler.net) or at least FreshLib library from the above IDE and FASM compiler of any kind.

Comment: Can you show an example using rdtsc? I tried searching for examples but I can't find anything that's simple enough for me to understand.

Comment: @user2758902 - example added.